# How can I fill in missing values from the value on the left in R, but only for 1 row?

Tags: r

I need to fill in some missing values in R from the column to the left, but I only want to do it for certain rows.

My data looks like this:

```
structure(list(...2 = c(NA, NA, "2 - 3", "3 - 4", "4 - 5"), ...4 = c("Wgt", 
"Port", NA, "2", "20"), ...5 = c("Wgt", "Bench", "3", "9", "20"
), ...6 = c("Wgt", "+/-", "Wgt", "-1", "-12"), ...7 = c("Pos", 
"Port", "Wgt", "-10", NA), ...8 = c("Pos", "Bench", NA, NA, NA
), ...9 = c("Pos", "+/-", NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -5L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I want the first row to look like:

```
structure(list(...2 = c(NA, NA, "2 - 3", "3 - 4", "4 - 5"), ...4 = c("Wgt", 
"Port", NA, "2", "20"), ...5 = c("NA", "Bench", "3", "9", "20"
), ...6 = c("NA", "+/-", "Wgt", "-1", "-12"), ...7 = c("Pos", 
"Port", "Wgt", "-10", NA), ...8 = c("NA", "Bench", NA, NA, NA
), ...9 = c("NA", "+/-", NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

In this example I only want the missing NA values filled in for row 1. The other missing value need to stay.

I tried using the zoo code below, but it will fill in the NAs for the entire data set.

```
library(zoo)
new.data <-new.data %>%
    mutate(...4 = as.character(...4)) %>%
    pmap_dfr(., ~ na.locf(c(...)) %>%
        as.list %>%
        as_tibble)
```

I'm using R 3.5.3

Is there a way to tell R to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Please do not post images of data. Share a reproducible example (you can use `dput()` to do that)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the suggestion of Matt, this is the code I created.

```
# Takes the row of the data that we want to work with and puts it in a new df.
new.data2 <- new.data[1,]

# it assigns NA values to the last known value to the left.
new.data2 <-new.data2 %>%
  mutate(...4 = as.character(...4)) %>%
  pmap_dfr(., ~ na.locf(c(...)) %>%
             as.list %>%
             as_tibble)

# combines the two data sets
new.data <- rbind(new.data2, new.data)
# removes the original row that we did the operation on 
new.data <- new.data[-c(2),]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign NA to those columns by slicing, then mutating the values to NA, and then rbind to create a final dataframe:

There's probably a more elegant way to do this, but here it is.

```
library(dplyr)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
library(naniar)

df_new <- df %>%
  slice(1) %>%
  mutate("...5" = NA) %>%
  mutate("...6" = NA) %>%
  mutate("...8" = NA) %>%
  mutate("...9" = NA)

df <- df %>%
  slice(2:n())

final <- rbind(df_new, df)
```

Comment: I couldn't get your code to work, but your approach to solving the problem was very helpful. I followed your suggestion, separated that one row, did the operation on it, and then rbind it back into the original data set. I'll place the code I used below. Thanks for your help.